# Creating front-end forms like in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I was curious if there was a way to replicate the Django admin interface - specifically the forms when adding an object - in the front end... Here's my scenario:

```
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class SubArea(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, null=True, blank=True)
    subarea = models.ForeignKey(SubArea, null=True, blank=True)
```

So If I setup a form in the frontend for the Product model, I have no way of adding Area or SubArea objects.  In the Django admin, however, I'm able to easily add these objects by clicking the "+" next to the fields.

I am looking for the easiest possible solution (while still being secure) to allow for fronted creating of the Foreign Keys without having to setup separate forms.  Not sure *if* that is even possible, but wanted to reach out to the community for advice.

Thanks!
J

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. The admin is written in Django, so anything possible there is possible in your own code. But all clicking the + button does is pop up a window which displays the "Add Area" form, which you can easily replicate, surely?

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I know this *can* be added manually, but I was curious if there was a way to implement that is as simple as using {{ form.as_p }} - basically having Django handle the form output without having to write a lot of extra code to achieve the same functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django admin makes extensive use of formsets, see below:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/

Regarding your query with adding the '+' a la Django admin, you can acheive this with the RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper which you can find [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py).

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience the easiest way of adding, editing, updating corresponding(related) items on a Form on the front-end, same way like in the django-Admin, is using ["django-addanother"](http://django-addanother.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which you can use from [here](http://django-addanother.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Easy, fast and clean solution on this problem and it works with Django 1.11 too. And it has good documentation, demo also.

Answer (score 0):

`django-form-admin` (.. let enter more characters stackoverflow needs 30 for answer)